# Marketing Cloud Broken outlook mail format

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am creating a template in marketing cloud, using a blank template.

[image]

The problem is when I get an email to Gmail looks good, but when it is outlook comes out as it does not work the image scaling. This is what I have seen with the tests, in other environments this problem does not happen to me, I do not know if anyone has happened something similar.

I deduced this scaling problem because I tried to remove the check and I saw that gmail had the same formatting as outlook.

[image]

any help or possible leads would be appreciated

Comment: Scale to fit doesn't work in some versions of Outlook. If you can share a screenshot it can help... Generically OUTLOOK issues with respect to Images occur when you use images with dimensions greater than the width of the actual email... Example: You cannot use a 1200px width image for a 600px email (it works in other domains) `I recommend resizing ur image to email width` and re-check.